# Variable size of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, scikit-image

I am loading an image using `skimage.io.imread` and saving the image as numpy array. Following is the inferance:

Original image: `(256x512x3)`

[image]

Following is the code that I execute:

```
img = io.imread(img_file) # 48.1 kB
i1, i2 = img[:, :256], img[:, 256:]
np.save('i1', i1) # 196.7 kB
np.save('i2', i2) # 196.7 kB
final_image = np.empty([1, 2, 256, 256, 3])
final_image[0, 0], final_image[0, 1] = i1, i2
np.save('final', final_image) # 3.1 MB
```

Can anyone explain why such a huge difference in the size of the image?

EDIT: dtype of `i1`, `i2`, `final_image` is `np.float64`

Comment: Well, for starters, `final_image` is of dtype `np.float_`, which is likely 8 bytes per item.

Comment: The dtype of `i1` and `i2` is `np.float_` as well. But I don't see such a surge in the size of the saved array

Comment: Um, pretty sure it isn't. It should be defaulting to reading in as `np.uint8`, at least it does on my system.

Comment: Can you actually print out `final_mage.shape, final_image.dtype`

Comment: Yes, that's right, `i1` and `i2` have dtype of `uint8` whereas `final_image` has `float64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.empty` will default to whatever `np.float_` is on your system, however, your image should have been read in as `np.uint8`, so provide the corresponding `dtype` to `empty`:

```
final_image = np.empty([1, 2, 256, 256, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem. Even though specifying dtype to be of `uint8`, it changes to `float64`

Comment: It's changing at least on my system

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was making changes to the code in a different file and executing another file. I am sorry